# Como colocar uma Expandable ListView em uma Aba?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Opa,

Não consigo configurar esse tipo de listView em uma ABA.

Por exemplo, eu tenho a tela 1 quando clico no botão da tela 1 ela vai para a tela que quero colocar a aba (com nome dos campus da faculdade).

Só que dentro de cada aba, quero colocar os meses do ano e expandir quando clicar, mostrando os eventos.

Só que não consigo fazer isso de jeito nenhum.

Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Você não sabe implementar uma Expandable ListView ou apenas não sabe como implementá-la numa aba?

Comment: Os dois. Não sei colocar o Expandable dentro da aba